# skype notifications not working

Tags: windows-7, skype, notifications

My notifications in skype are not working when someone sends me a message. They do work for the first message, so it is not a general problem with the notifications.

How can I fix this?

All options in the notifications tab are checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution  is to check the conversation notification settings. Those can then be changed show the notification every time the user sends me an IM.